# ec2 instance running locust.io issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, locust

I'm trying to run a locust.io load test on an ec2 instance - a t2.micro. I fire up 50 concurrent users, and initially everything works fine, with the CPU load reaching ~15%. After an hour or so though, the network out shows a drop of about 80% -

[image]

Any idea why this is happening? It's certainly not due to CPU credits. Maybe I reached the network limits for a t2 micro instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not a CPU credit issue?  Can you check your cpu credits over that same time period to see how they look?

Or better yet, run the same test on a non-t2 instance.  One that isn't limited in it's CPU usage.

t2.micro's consume CPU credits at usage about 10% of CPU.